# Angular: conditional class for duplicates within ngFor

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, duplicates, ngfor

There is a code

```
<li *ngFor="let color of colors;" [class.duplicate]="color.hex == colors[0].hex">{{color.hex}}<li>
```

that populates the list of hex code based on the hex properties of the color object of the list of colors.

As result, the `duplicate` class above is assigned to any item where hex is the same as the hex of the **0th item**.

Correct?

Is it possible to modify this code so that `duplicate` class  applied to any duplicates, but not just compared to `0th` item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to add a function to your controller. My Angular2+ is rusty, but something to the effect of:

`<li *ngFor="let color of colors;" [class.duplicate]="findDuplicate(index, color)">{{color.hex}}<li>`

```
function findDuplicate(index, color){
    return colors.find((checkColor, checkIndex) => {
        let isDuplicate = (checkIndex != index) && (color.hex == checkColor.hex);
        return isDuplicate;
    });
}
```

Note: The `checkIndex != index` is to prevent flagging the current color as a duplicate when it finds itself in the array.